# PHP, virtual file from a string without writing to hard disk

Tags: php

If I have a string (containing a PDF file) is it possible to make a "virtual" file to avoid writing to the hard disk, to be later used in a function which requires an existing file?

```
// theorical code

$file=stringToVirtualFile($string);

require($file);
```

Comment: Yes. We call them "variables" and store them in "memory".

Comment: If `$string` is a PDF file, why would you `require()` it in that manner? If I understand correctly, that would have the same effect as echoing `$string`, unless there happened to be any `<?` byte patterns in the PDF, in which case it would likely encounter a syntax error.

Comment: @Fraxtil, this is "theorical code", the real code is for a custom php function who requires a "phisical" file c:

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can [use the special php://memory](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) to have a file handle that reference in-memory data instead of data written to a file. You may also use php://temp to have a file backed memory store (where the file will be written to disk if it exceeds 2MB by default).