# Send RS232 data from an always running while-loop Python script to HTML via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, serial-port

I'm a bit new to AJAX and using serial ports, hope you can guide me.

I have a measuring device that sends data over an RS232 port to a web server.
My website has to display that data in a constantly refreshing manner.

In order to achieve this, I'm using a python script with the Pyserial API.
The measuring device has to be initialized with an "I" command and asked for measurement data with an "M" command.

I am using AJAX to constantly reopen this python script every 250 milliseconds trough a middleman php file that just runs an exec command. And it gets the job done. But I feel that's an incredibly stupid and tasking way to constantly be initializing and closing the connection again and again, and using php as a middle man for python-ajax comunication.

So my question is: Can data be sent from within a while-loop python file that is constantly running to my web page by AJAX or some other means?

My python script:**rs232.py**

```
import json
import random
import time
import serial

port = "COM3"
baudrate = 9600
ser = serial.Serial(port, baudrate,bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS,parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, timeout=1, xonxoff=True)

if ser.isOpen():
    start=1;     
cmd="I"
ser.write((cmd +'\r\n').encode())
out = ''
time.sleep(0.08)
while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
    out += (ser.read(1)).decode()

cmd="M"
ser.write((cmd +'\r\n').encode())
out = ''
time.sleep(0.08)
while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
    out += (ser.read(1)).decode()

if out != '':
    my_string=out

ser.close()

new=[x.strip() for x in my_string.split(',')]
x1=float(new[-1])


D = {'x1':x1, 'start': start}

print (json.dumps(D))
```

My php middle man:**rs232.php**

```
<?php
$python="C:\........\python.exe";
$result=json_decode(exec($python.' rs232.py'), true);
$x1=$result['x1'];
$y=array("x1" => $x1);
echo json_encode($y);
?>
```

And my javascript code:**page.php**

```
$(function() {   
    var repeat= function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "config/rs232.php",
            success: function(data) {
                var rs232data=JSON.parse(data);
                document.getElementById("militron").innerHTML=rs232data.x1;
                }
        });
    }

    setInterval(function(){repeat()}, 250);
});
```

Comment: You can host a python server using a library like `flask`. Then you can build an all in one python script where you have two threads, the first communicating with `pyserial` and the second running the server. Another alternative is to constantly make the python script write to a file and read this file in PHP. Is your webpage static? In case you are using HTTP requests, you will have to keep sending `GET` requests to the server.

Comment: The servers in running on a Raspberry Pi 3 with python already installed. The website is dynamic and is using PHP to call forth different entry forms in which I do some math calculations, and POST data to an SQL database.

I'm not at all familiar with flask, except hearing about it from time to time, so I would really like to avoid it for now. Not putting extra strain on the raspberry is also a plus.

I like your second suggestion. Could you please link me an example or maybe make one with the python script just generating a random number in a while loop to keep it simple.

Comment: Wrote an answer, is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the second suggestion in my comment, here's what you can do on your server. You could constantly write to a text file after some delay.

```
import time

number = 0
while(True):
    # Keeping some delay here, replace this with pyserial code
    time.sleep(1)
    number = number + 1
    f = open("serial_data.txt", 'w')
    f.write(str(number))
    f.close()
```

Now in your PHP script,

```
<?php
    $data = file_get_contents('serial_data.txt');
    echo $data;
?>
```

Comment: For more complicated data, write JSON objects

Comment: Thank you!! This is exactly what I wanted.
Works like a charm :D

Comment: That's great! Happy to help. Let me know if you run into more issues

Comment: Since you ask. 
I am now wondering if there is a way to write data to a virtual file in RAM that can be accessed from PHP? In order to avoid constantly writing to disk.

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409250/php-virtual-file-from-a-string-without-writting-on-hard-disk

Comment: I found a super simple solution. Linux systems have easily available shared memory by using the file location **/dev/shm**. More about that here: [link](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/what-is-devshm-and-its-practical-usage.html)

Comment: Awesome, maybe you could drop an answer in that question ^